# Dynamically add fields to input dialog

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

Is it possible to somehow add input fields to an input dialog (`inputdlg()`) in MATLAB when a specific event occurs, e.g. the user types in a certain value in one of the existing fields...?
Or is there any other 'hacky' way to achieve this so that the user doesn't have to click "OK" and I have to code to reopen another input dialog which contains more input fields.. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inputdlg` is not a built in function, so you might as well copy it, call it by another name and change its functionality.

Comment: Yeah I know this but I really don't know how to achieve this, that's why I'm asking for an existing solution!?